# TFS Continuous Integration Build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have created 3 continuous integration builds under same source control folder i.e under one TFS folder, there are 22 projects and 3 solutions under this folder, each solution contains some shared projects. I have created a continuous integration build for each of the 3 solution files. The problem is whenever anyone checks in under any solution all 3 builds are triggering. Is there any way to trigger the related build only if there is any check-in under the any solution ? Please let me know how to configure 'Items to build' and source setting tabs in TFS 2012 ?

Answer (score 3):

### TFS 2015u1 and older

The Source Control Folders in the mapping govern when a CI build triggers, nothing else. A custom Activity might be able to check that no changes were made in specific folders and prematurely stop the build, but that requires you to create a custom activity and customize the workflow.

Normally you'd place each solution and its projects in their own folder in Source Control, that way you can create a source control mapping for each specific CI build.

---

### TFS 2015 update 2 and onwards:

The new build engine supports separate definitions for workspaces and triggers.

Comment: What about projects shared between solutions?

Comment: Give them a separate build and package them up in a NuGet package, or have multiple builds trigger when these files change.

Comment: The second option - to clarify, you suggest placing each solution and it's projects in their own folder, but have references to projects outside of the folder (add those common projects to solution too)?

Comment: If at all possible. Don't reference the project files from other solutions. But if you need to trigger in them independently it may be the only way to go if you can't do a proper solution with a nuget package or simply copying over the assembly outputs.